# Calculate the direction based on degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, graph, trigonometry

So I'm working on a particle emitter with javascript and canvas.
And I want to be able to set what direction the particles are emitting based on an angle.

This can be done with this function:

```
y = Math.tan(45 * Math.PI/180);
```

Which returns 1 if the angle is 45. etc.

But I don't exacly know how I should implement this since pixels are calculated a little different. Think -1 as removing one pixel each step and 1 as adding one pixel.

If the angle is 45, Y is 1 and X is 1 which is correct.
But to get a pixel traveling at 315 degrees Y is -1 and X should be 1.
And at 225 degrees Y should be -1 (but is 1) and X should be -1.

How should the function look like if it should work like this?

Here is an image of how im thinking:
(The emitter is in the origin.)

[image: The emitter is in origin]

Comment: If you want the slope..and you have an `x` and a `y` difference in pixels...then it's just `y / x`.

Comment: Map angles to the first quadrant, figure out your X and Y, and then adjust the sign(s) accordingly.

Comment: Are you saying you want to know what pixels are touched by the path?

Comment: I have never learned this is school so I am quite new to this. So I'm not sure exacly what I'm asking for. But I cant figure ouy how to get X

Comment: I would reverse your angular direction and just use polar coordinates

Comment: Be very careful with tangent as a function over 360 degrees  it has singularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's simple,

```
angle = (angle * Math.PI/180) % 360;
tangent = Math.tan(angle);
```

Since you do not know where is x;

```
section_x_positive = (angle<90||angle>270?1:-1);
section_y_positive = (angle>0&&angle<180?1:-1);
x = abs(tangent) * section_x_positive;
y = abs(tangent) * section_y_positive;
```

Comment: I changed the code a little bit, try this one. Changed again:)

Comment: Doesn't seem to exactly work as it should. If the angle is 45 then x is 0.9999 and y is -0.9999. But X shouldn't be 1 and so should Y. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzYje/

Comment: Edited the code, you want normal coordinate system angles. ok then, try it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your problem is that you're thinking about direction, which is a vector quantity, as if it were a scalar.

You need to remember that a 2D vector is represented as two components:

[image]

[image]

You can work in terms of unit vectors, so the magnitude r = 1.

So if you have a direction angle, which should be measured in radians, increasing in the counterclockwise direction, and starting at the x = 0 horizontal axis, you'll end up with two components of the unit vector that points in the direction you want.